SFMCSDK Android Crash java.lang.NullPointerException:
Sometimes we receive crashes with :
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.stats.b.d()' on a null object reference
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.stats.c$a.a (SourceFile:58)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run (SourceFile:18)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

SDK version 8.1.5
Is this a known issue or are we doing something wrong?
Unfortunately, for now, we weren't able to reproduce it, so we have only crashlytics logs
Android Versions : 8.0-14
Thx for your help!
Update: It seems that is the cause : https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000suidb/mobilepush-applications-crash-or-error-when-processing-analytics-error-enclosed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

updated , it seems we have some crash in the sdk internals but not clear what is the cause
